# MySQL - JSON field or separate table for large dataset?

Tags: mysql, bigdata

**Note:** I searched and couldn't find any duplicated topic. Please don't get it wrong with other *Large Dataset* related topics.

Here is what I'm facing to:

Per each request, I have to store 1000 to 50,000 datasets along with the request information.

What I have to do with the generated datasets:

- Doing some math
- Retrieving and paginating

---

*Now, I'm thinking of these approaches:*

1. Create one table to store request info and another related table to
   store datasets.
2. Create one table to store request info with one JSON field to store all datasets as JSON objects.
3. A combination of 1 and 2. One table for the request. One table for datasets. But, chunk datasets to small buckets and store them in a JSON field in table `dataset`.
4. Something you recommend and I didn't think of.

---

Example of table schemas:

*Approach #1*:

table **request**: `id (int unsigned)`, `user_id (int)`, `ip (varchar)`, `dataset_count (smallint unsigned)`

table **dataset**: `id (bigint)`, `request_id (int unsigned)`, `timestamp (int unsigned)`, `cycles (tinyint)`, `probability (tinyint)`

---

*Approach #2*:

table **request**: `id (int unsigned)`, `user_id (int)`, `ip (varchar)`, `dataset_count (smallint unsigned)`, `datasets (json)`

---

*Approach #3*:

table **request**: `id (int unsigned)`, `user_id (int)`, `ip (varchar)`, `dataset_count (smallint unsigned)`

table **dataset**: `id (bigint)`, `request_id (int unsigned)`, `sequence_no (smallint)`, `chunked_datasets (json)`

---

Considering the performance and I/O efficiency, I'd like to pick the right approach before drawing the structure.

Is there anyone who has some experience in a similar case?

Sharing knowledge is appreciated.

Comment: Do a small test database for each method. Do some testing on them performing the operations you're going to need to do, and see which one works best for you with your particular requirements. (My guess is that given the operations you've listed, you're gong to find JSON is not the best path to take.)

Comment: You can't evaluate which one of these approaches has better efficiency or performance unless you know the queries. Table structures alone don't have performance -- *queries* have performance. So you must evaluate the types of queries you expect to run against these tables to make a decision about which one is best for your queries.

Comment: @KenWhite I appreciate your response. Preparing data to test in this case takes significant time. I am gonna do it anyways. But, I wanted to see if someone already has experience with a similar scenario. So, sharing experiences could help a lot and save time.

Comment: @BillKarwin, queries will be to retrieve paginated datasets to show `timestamps`, `cycles`, and `probability`. Also, `sum` and `avg` on each of these fields.

Comment: Are there a total of 50K "datasets"?  Or billions?  Will there be a lot of redundancy in the "datasets" for one request to another?

Comment: Probability of what?  Avg of what?

Comment: @RickJames, There could be up to 50k dataset per request. Means, it's possible to lead to billions of datasets in total for thousands of requests. Also, if you look into the table structure of approach #1, you'd notice `probability` is a field which it's value coming from some calculation. It could be any number.

Comment: @Mojtaba - Do the math.  How many terabytes are you anticipating?

Comment: @RickJames that's a smart question. Actually, the size of datasets for each request could vary between 1 to 15 MB. And, in a few months, I might meet a couple TeraBytes only for datasets. I am planning on an archiving process every 6 months. So, I think it's fair to say I am anticipating up to 3TB

Comment: @Mojtaba - Then you need to find a way to avoid duplications.  It sounds like `dataset` is the biggie; let's focus on what it contains, where the comes from, etc.  Although it is possible to work with 3TB, the answer to your Question about Json or not (etc) does not have an obvious answer.  There are too many potential roadblocks.  One roadblock is network bandwidth.

Comment: @RickJames. Thanks for your advice. Actually, I am trying to prepare a simulation. And, about the duplications, they are part of the process and I'm not supposed to remove the duplications. And, about the network bandwidth, reading data is gonna be paginated. So, there shouldn't be a huge amount of data passing through the network. However, as I mentioned before, I am planning to dig into the approaches and find out which one is better. But, I was wondering if someone else had a similar experience before to help me save time and effort

Comment: @Mojtaba - Shovelling that much data _into_ the tables takes up huge bandwidth.  Pagination, especially via `OFFSET` may not help.  "Not supposed to remove dups" -- Why?  Offhand, it sounds like a decision made by a manager ignorant of databases.  I suspect your requires are quite unlike anyone else's.  In my experience, _every_ multi-TB database has _different_ issues.  There are some common underlying principles (normalizing, summary tables, sharding, etc); I am fishing for enough understanding of the task to help you in some direction.

Comment: @RickJames, I appreciate the time you put on it. I have to confess the project use case definition is weird. So, I do not really expect someone gives me a perfect answer. Shedding some lights could help. Saying that, the concerns you shared could be helpful too. I guess I should find a better view once I do some simulated tests. I am projecting being able to do some prior test/comparision within next two weeks. I will update this post by my results. They might become helpful for someone else.